# Symfony: the route "xxx" does not exist

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I uploaded my project to the server. Everything worked great locally but in the server, once a click a link or try to go manually (writing the direction in the module/template way), I get the error "The route "xxx" does not exist."

Please help me out, I'm out of ideas.

Thanks!

**---Routing.yml---**

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*

**---Error Message---**

More info about the error:
500 | Internal Server Error | sfConfigurationException

The route "xxx" does not exist.

stack trace at () in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/routing/sfPatternRouting.class.php line 313 ...
      // named route

```
  if (!isset($this->routes[$name]))
  {
    throw new sfConfigurationException(sprintf('The route "%s" does not exist.', $name));
  }

  $route = $this->routes[$name];

  $this->ensureDefaultParametersAreSet();
```

Comment: Which version of Symfony do you use ? 1.4 ?

Comment: Have you tried to clear Symfony cache on your server ? Could you copy-paste the content of your `routing.yml` file into your question ? Check this as well: http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/37238/

Comment: Sounds like symfony cc is needed.

Comment: As well as the routing.yml, it would be really helpful to know the URL that you're actually requesting, and the actual route that Symfony is telling you doesn't exist.

Comment: @Frosty: Thanks for your comments! I am using symfony 1.4 and tried clear cache on the server several times. I copied the content of routing.yml in the question.

Comment: @Matt How do I check the exact route that's not being found? I only get the error page that is written in the question... Thanks!

Comment: To use route by name you must to declare it in routing.yml. You routing.yml contains two default routes (default, default_index)

Comment: @Hans We can only really help if you're willing to tell us (a) a URL that you're requesting, and (b) the route that symfony is telling you does not exist when you request that URL, i.e. the bit you've replaced with "xxx" in your question.

Comment: @Hans What about development mode? Is there same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear symfony cache on your production:

```
./symfony cc
```

Comment: I did several times, had no effect.

Comment: Solved it! It was a stupid thing. I had a module name spelled with uppercase and it needed to be with camelcase.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify `routing.yml` file. If you have not define any rules for that link than it will display a fatal error:

for ex. :

```
link_to('Registration','user_registration')
```

In rounting.yml :

```
user_registration:
  url: /register/userRegistration.html
  param: {module: register, action: userRegistration}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may used link_to tag any where in page and you may provide there xxx in link url value. have to provide there module/action pattern or add xxx routing rule in routing.yml file